# SSRS Navigation Options

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am looking to enhance the web interface of my SSRS instance (2016). Are there any options to use tabs or a left hand report hierarchical tree to navigate between the reports?

Currently all I can see is the ability to go up a level then be presented with a list of the reports available in that level.

Are there any other options or generally accepted solutions for better navigation within SSRS?

One thing that caught my eye was document maps. Is there a way to create a document map which enables report navigation? Not navigation within a report, but navigation to another report?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Have not tried it, but if you had a data connection to the reportserver database, create a dataset to list certain report items, and make HTML links to navigate to that specific report? Not sure the best visual tool to have this, but have a textbox action set to go to that report dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I use a report to view all the deployed reports on the report server. It could get you part of the way there. The icons are links to folders/reports. I also show the execution count and subscription count. The XML code exceeds the limit in this answer. [Here's a shortcut to the XML/rdl file in GitHub](https://github.com/SQL-Server-projects/Reporting-Services-examples/blob/master/ServerReports/Report%20List.rdl). Copy and paste the XML into a text file then rename the text file with `.rdl` extension.

#### Screenshot of report preview

[image: ssrs report listing]

#### SQL for the report

```
/*
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Purpose:  To search deployed reports on the report server
| Note:     SQLCmdMode Script (from the SSMS menu [Query]|[SQLCMD Mode])
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

:setvar _server "YourServerNameHere"
:setvar _database "ReportServer"
--:setvar _user "***username***"
--:setvar _password "***password***"
--:connect $(_server) -U $(_user) -P $(_password)
:connect $(_server)

USE [$(_database)];
GO


DECLARE @ReportFolder AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ReportName AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ReportDescription AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @CreatedBy AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @CreatedDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @ModifiedBy AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ModifiedDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @ReportDefinition AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @SearchFor AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @SearchType AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @all_value AS VARCHAR(50)

SET @ReportFolder = '<ALL>'
SET @ReportName = NULL
SET @ReportDescription = NULL
SET @CreatedBy = NULL
SET @CreatedDate = NULL
SET @ModifiedBy = NULL
SET @ModifiedDate = NULL
SET @ReportDefinition = NULL
SET @SearchFor = NULL
SET @SearchType = NULL
SET @all_value = '<ALL>'

*/

;WITH
report_users 
AS
(
    SELECT [UserID], [SimpleUserName] = UPPER(RIGHT([UserName], (LEN([UserName])-CHARINDEX('\', [UserName])))) FROM dbo.[Users]
)
,
report_catalog
AS
(
    SELECT    
          rpt.[ItemID]
        , rpt.[CreatedById]
        , rpt.[ModifiedById]
        , rpt.[Type]
        , rpt.[Name] 
        , rpt.[Description]
        , rpt.Parameter
        , [CreationDate] = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), rpt.[CreationDate], 13))
        , [ModifiedDate] = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), rpt.[ModifiedDate], 13))
        , [ReportFolder] = SUBSTRING(rpt.[Path], 2, Len(rpt.[Path])-Len(rpt.[Name])-2) 
        , rpt.[Path]
        , [URL_ReportFolder] = 'http://' + Host_Name() + '/Reports/browse/'  + SUBSTRING(rpt.[Path], 2, Len(rpt.[Path])-Len(rpt.[Name])-2)
        , [URL_Report] = 'http://' + Host_Name() + '/Reports/report/'  + SUBSTRING(rpt.[Path], 2, Len(rpt.[Path])-Len(rpt.[Name])-2)  + '%2f' + rpt.[Name]
        , [ReportDefinition] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), rpt.[Content]))  
    FROM 
        dbo.[Catalog] AS rpt
    WHERE 
        1=1
        AND rpt.[Type] = 2
)
SELECT    
      rpt.ItemID
    , rpt.[Name]
    , rpt.[Description]
    , rpt.[Parameter]
    , [ReportCreatedBy] = urc.[SimpleUserName]
    , [ReportCreationDate] = rpt.[CreationDate]
    , [ReportModifiedBy] = urm.[SimpleUserName]
    , [ReportModifiedDate] = rpt.[ModifiedDate] 
    , rpt.[ReportFolder]
    , [ReportPath] = rpt.[Path]
    , rpt.[URL_ReportFolder]
    , rpt.[URL_Report]
    , rpt.[ReportDefinition]
    , [CommandText] = rpt.[ReportDefinition]
    , el.[ExecutionLogCount]
    , sc.[SubscriptionCount]
    , [SearchForStr] = ISNULL(@SearchFor, ' ') 
FROM  
    report_catalog AS rpt 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT [ExecutionLogCount] = COUNT([ReportID]), [ReportID] FROM dbo.[ExecutionLog] GROUP BY [ReportID]) el ON el.[ReportID] = rpt.[ItemID]
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT [SubscriptionCount] = COUNT([Report_OID]), [Report_OID] FROM dbo.[Subscriptions] GROUP BY [Report_OID]) sc ON sc.[Report_OID] = rpt.[ItemID]
    LEFT JOIN report_users AS urc ON rpt.[CreatedById] = urc.[UserID] 
    LEFT JOIN report_users AS urm ON rpt.[ModifiedById] = urm.[UserID]
WHERE 
    1=1
    AND (@all_value IN (@ReportFolder) OR rpt.[ReportFolder] IN(@ReportFolder))
    AND (@CreatedBy IS NULL OR urc.[SimpleUserName] LIKE '%' + @CreatedBy + '%')
    AND (@CreatedDate IS NULL OR rpt.[CreationDate] >= @CreatedDate)
    AND (@ModifiedBy IS NULL OR urm.[SimpleUserName] LIKE '%' + @ModifiedBy + '%')
    AND (@ModifiedDate IS NULL OR rpt.[ModifiedDate] >= @ModifiedDate)
    AND (
            @SearchFor IS NULL 
            OR (
                (rpt.[Name] LIKE '%' + @SearchFor + '%' AND (@all_value IN(@SearchType) OR 'Report Name' IN(@SearchType)))
                OR (rpt.[Description] LIKE '%' + @SearchFor + '%' AND (@all_value IN(@SearchType) OR 'Report Description' IN(@SearchType)) )
                OR (PATINDEX('%' + @SearchFor + '%', rpt.[ReportDefinition]) > 0 AND (@all_value IN(@SearchType) OR 'Report Definition' IN(@SearchType)) )   
                )
        )
```